# FCM backend with Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, app-engine-flexible

I want to use FCM & Firebase Realtime DB to allow messaging between users. The Realtime DB will work as a chat and the FCM messaging will be used to send notifications in case the other user app is not active.

I need a backend module, I want to use a Google Platform App-Engine with Android Studio. Is it possible to use the Standard App Engine to look for notifications request in the Realtime DB and then send messages through the FCM API (HTTP Post)? or do I have to implement the Flexible App Engine?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Firebase Java API in App engine

this example is pretty close to what you are trying to do it sounds like

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that the Standard App Engine can be used to access the Firebase Realtime DB, however I am not sure about sending POST request.